# Facebook graph api hide from timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im currently working on a new facebook applikation that posts a link through facebook graph like this:

```
   function posttowall(access_token) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?method=POST&url=http://google.com&access_token=' + access_token,
        dataType: 'script',
        success:function(data){

        //success wall post

        }
    });
}
```

I am trying to hide the post from the timeline, I have tried with

```
no_story=1
is_hidden=1
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Nothing changed at all

Comment: Why are you trying to hide it?

Comment: There is nothing in the official documentation that would suggest you can make a “hidden” post to a user timeline.